# Can someone give me a simple qt example?

Tags: qt

I want to implement a simple QT example: click the QPushButton to display a paragraph of text.

Like this:

[image]

I know there are many ways to implement it, but I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton;
//btn->show();
btn->setParent(this);
btn->setText("button 1");

QLabel *la = new QLabel(this);

connect(btn,&QPushButton::clicked,la,&QLabel::setText("show me"));
```

Anyone who can help me？

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create the QLabel with a predefined text and hide it. On clicking the button, show it. So, `QLabel::hide` and `QLabel::show` could be used here. Just take care of the coordinates where you show the label because it would overlap the button itself without layout or proper coordinates.

Example (`mainwindow.cpp`, constructor):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowTitle("My App");                      // title bar text

    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(this);
    btn->setText("Click Me!");

    QLabel *la = new QLabel(this);
    la->setText("Show Me!");                       // set label text in advance
    la->move(100, 100);                            // set label position
    la->hide();                                    // hide label on load

    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, la, &QLabel::show);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Output (after clicking the image):

[image]